# How to improve speed of draw circle in mousemove [ JS / CANVAS ]

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I create a script which allow me to draw circle during mousemove, but it's not fast. Before drawing circle, I get the color pixel during mousemove to draw on canvas a circle with the color picked.

> I found on github this [increase performance on html canvas mousemove image mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850516/increase-performance-on-html-canvas-mousemove-image-mask)

I can't use this solution because I need to have pixel color to draw circle

I show you what I want

[image]

Some code

```
handlerMousemove: function(e) {
      canvasEevents.circleMousemove(e)
},

circleMousemove: function(e) {
     if(mousedown.allowBlur) {
          var x = (e.clientX - 200) / (zoomValue / 100)
          var y = (e.clientY - 38 - 25) / (zoomValue / 100)

         //circleBlur(x, y)
         circleBlurPixi(x, y)
     }
 },

function circleBlurPixi(x, y) {
    var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

    graphics.beginFill(0xe74c3c);
    graphics.drawCircle(x, y, 100);
    graphics.endFill();

    pixi_canvas.stage.addChild(graphics);
}
```

**UPDATE :**
[image: Result]

As you can see there is two line, the first one is when I drag slowly and the second one is the preoblem when drag quickly

I just want to have the same result when I drag quickly

Answer (score 0):

Every mousemove it creates a graphic, I think this causes the bad performance. You can try to add a global graphics, then every time you want to draw circle, just draw it to the global graphics.

Comment: I put this `var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();` in global var but That changes nothing. I put UPDATE in post to tell you what happened

Comment: var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
pixi_canvas.stage.addChild(graphics);

Put these code to global, and pls mind that don't let the image covers this graphics (you can use addChildAt(image, 0) to place the image to the bottom level).

Comment: Oh, I know what you meant, you can draw lines (use moveTo and lineTo) instead of drawing circle.

Comment: I already thought to do that but I need to draw like paint tool, without line, do you understand ? If you want I can share you my code on github ?

Comment: You can check this example: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-simple . It uses lines approach.

Comment: @Andrey Thank's a lot, I will try

Comment: Thank you it was what I want

Comment: @Andrey, sorry I made a misktake, with your link, I don't have the desired result. Indeed, when I use drawline I can't add blur during drawing

Comment: You can add the blur filter to graphics `graphics.filters = [blurFilter];` then drawlines on it.